# How do I export adjustbox-parameters?

Tags: scaling, adjustbox

I have got two `adjustbox`es (from the [adjustbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package). Now I need to give the second box the same totalheight as the one which the first box got.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[etex=true,export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{width={\textwidth},totalheight={8cm},keepaspectratio}
...some content ...
\end{adjustbox}

(In between is some text and a page break.)

\begin{adjustbox}{totalheight={<the same as in the first adjustbox>},keepaspectratio}
...other content...
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

I can't use the `8cm` (in the real document there is another variable instead of a fixed value),
because the height might be smaller if the box needed to be scaled down because it was too wide.
Adjustbox says that `\totalheight` would contain this height, but how do I export this to be re-used in the second box?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`adjustbox` has now keys for this kind of stuff. In your case use `gstore totalheight=\somelengthregister` to store the total height. If you need more dimension have a look at `gstore sizes` and other keys described in the packae manual in section 4.14 Store box content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newlength\mylength

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{width={\textwidth},totalheight={8cm},keepaspectratio,gstore totalheight=\mylength}
 ... some content ...
\end{adjustbox}

(In between is some text and a page break.) 

\begin{adjustbox}{totalheight=\mylength,keepaspectratio}
 ...other content...
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

---

#### Original answer

There are no key options yet to store the size of an `adjustbox`, but I was already thinking to add them. The value of `\totalheight` can only be used in keys which affect the size. These actually box the content and therefore update this length to have the correct value. You can however do the required boxing yourself using some small code added using the `precode` key, by using features of the `collectbox` package, which is internally used by `adjustbox` anyway. You need a length register which is assigned globally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[etex=true,export]{adjustbox}
\newlength\mylength
\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{width={\textwidth},totalheight={8cm},keepaspectratio,precode={\collectbox{\global\setlength\mylength{\totalheight}\BOXCONTENT}}}
  ... some content ...
\end{adjustbox}

(In between is some text and a page break.)

\begin{adjustbox}{totalheight=\mylength,keepaspectratio}
 ...other content...
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

If you need this more often then you can define a new key for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[etex=true,export]{adjustbox}
\newlength\mylength

\makeatletter
\define@key{adjbox}{settototalheight}[1]{%
    \Gin@esetsize
    \@tempswatrue
    \adjust@addcode{\@collectbox{\global#1=\totalheight\relax\BOXCONTENT}}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{width={\textwidth},totalheight={8cm},keepaspectratio,settototalheight=\mylength}
  ... some content ...
\end{adjustbox}

(In between is some text and a page break.)

\begin{adjustbox}{totalheight=\mylength,keepaspectratio}
 ...other content...
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to add the key at the very end, because the order is significant.

Comment: It works (as your answers always do), but I was really surprised that `\fitsinglefig...\captionsetup...\begin{table}[H]\begin{leftfullpage}\raggedleft\makeatletter\begin{adjustbox}{width={\textwidth},totalheight={\fitfigheight},keepaspectratio,precode={\collectbox{\global\setlength\@tempdimc{\totalheight}\BOXCONTENT\xdef\ajbStotalheight{\@tempdimc}}}}\begin{tabular}...<end everything, new page>\noindent\captionsetup...\begin{table}[H]\begin{fullpage}\begin{adjustbox}{valign=b,totalheight={\ajbStotalheight},keepaspectratio}\begin{tabular}...` worked without any further problem! +1 and accepted.

Comment: Note that `\xdef\ajbStotalheight{\@tempdimc}` doesn't make much sense. Dimensions aren't expandable. Either write `\the\@tempdimc` instead of `\@tempdimc` to expand to its current value, or directly `\xdef\ajbStotalheight{\the\totalheight}`, before or after `\BOXCONTENT`.

Comment: The limited number of characters of a comment and the wrong place to shorten the code... - thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Stephen: I just added a key like this to `adjustbox`, but with a different name. It will be in the next release.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I see is to set the first box in a storage bin and measure it

```
% in the preamble
\newsavebox{\stephenbox}
\newlength{\stephenlength}

% in the document
\sbox{\stephenbox}
  {\begin{adjustbox}{width={\textwidth},totalheight={8cm},keepaspectratio}
   ...some content ...
   \end{adjustbox}}%
\setlength{\stephenlength}{\ht\stephenbox}%
\addtolength{\stephenlength}{\dp\stephenbox}%
\usebox{\stephenbox}

some lines later

\begin{adjustbox}{totalheight=\stephenlength,keepaspectratio}
...other content...
\end{adjustbox}
```

Comment: While your solution generally works (+1), I had hoped for an "in-adjustbox-package-solution" instead of boxing and measuring it. Martin Scharrer provided that. Could have send an e-mail to him, because he is the author/maintainer of the 
adjustbox package, but his solution here could also help other people with a similar problem. - `\end{leftfullpage}` resets `\stephenlength` to `0pt`, but I did not mention in my question that the adjustbox is inside a `\makeatletter` inside `\raggedleft` inside `\begin{leftfullpage}` inside `\begin{table}[H]` inside `\captionsetup` inside `\fitsinglefig`...

Comment: @Stephen While my hack works, a solution based on `adjustbox` keywords is surely better.